# Clickable points on Three.js globe

Tags: three.js

I have looked into using three.js but could not find any examples specific to what I need.

I am trying to create a 3D Map (on a globe) that has 3 different pin points around the world.  I'd like to be able to detect which pinpoint was clicked on, in order to display information elsewhere on the page.

Is anyone aware of a way to do this?  Any demos or tutorials would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: https://experiments.withgoogle.com/chrome/globe

Comment: Thanks, I had not stumbled across that yet.  I still was unable to find any examples where the points were clickable?

Comment: @Samantha Depends on what you mean with "points". Are they `THREE.Points()`, or `THREE.Sprite()`, or `THREE.Mesh()`? Anyway, there are several official [examples](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=interactive#webgl_interactive_points) of how to interact with different objects in a scene

Comment: use a raycaster, then use `intersectObect` to get the object.

Answer (score 1):

Use an event listener to fire off a [raycaster](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Raycaster) on mouse click. I quickly cut and pasted some code from one of my projects so that it does a raycast from the mouse in screenspace to an object in 3D space and updates the color of the material to red.

This should at least get you started in the right direction:

```
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(0,0);
var raygun = new THREE.Raycaster();
var useRaycast = true;

// Raycast when we click the mouse
function onClick() {
    // Get mouse position in screen space
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    // Only raycast if not panning (optimization)
    var hits;
    if (useRaycast) {
        raygun.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

        // Raycast to single object
        hits = raygun.intersectObject(myTargetObect, false);

        // Raycast to multiple objects
        // hits = raygun.intersectObjects([myTargetObect, myTargetObect2]);
    }

    // Run if we have intersections
    if (hits.length > 0) {

        for (var i = 0; i < hits.length; i++ ) {
            // Change material color of item we clicked on
            hits[i].object.material.color.set(0xff0000);
        }

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
```

MrDoob also has an [example on github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html) with a [web demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes).